# Load video url into FFmpegFrameGrabber

Tags: android, javacv

Does JavaCV FFmpegFrameGrabber support using a url as a video source?

I've tried using:

```
grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4");
grabber.setFormat("mp4");
grabber.start()
```

But `start()` throws the following error

```
org.bytedeco.javacv.FrameGrabber$Exception: avformat_open_input() error -5: Could not open input "http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4". (Has setFormat() been called?)
```

By the way I'm developing in Android and everything works great using a video file from the sd-card.

Thanks!

Comment: hahaha.. sorry guys, I realized that I hadn't included the INTERNET permission into the manifest.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @Magda, on my case it was a missing INTERNET permission inside the manifest -- which prevented the FFMPEGFrameGrabber to access the internet.